# Angular CLI | Mac OS | Dependency Issue during installation

Tags: macos, angular, angular-cli

Installing Angluar CLI on MacOS (Sierra, 10.12.4), during which having the following dependency issue.

```
└─┬ angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3
  └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@^5.0.1
```

node -v : v7.10.0
npm -v : 4.2.0

Tried removing rxjs completely and let it installed as a part of the dependency tree of the CLI, still gives the same error. Any ideas folks?

Cheer,
D

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with `npm`, you can check it out here:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1341#issuecomment-20634338

You can fix your issue by manually installing `rxjs@^5.0.1` globally with

```
npm install -g rxjs@^5.0.1
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already tried this, it's just that the same error being repeated.